# Десериализация сложного JSON объекта C#

Tags: c#, json

Имеется сложный, не стандартный JSON объект:

```
{
    "id": "62",
    "contact_id": "1",
    "create_datetime": "2017-10-27 01:05:48",
    "update_datetime": null,
    "state_id": "new",
    "total": "332.2800",
    "currency": "RUB",
    "rate": "1.00000000",
    "tax": "0.0000",
    "shipping": "0.0000",
    "discount": "0.0000",
    "assigned_contact_id": null,
    "paid_year": null,
    "paid_quarter": null,
    "paid_month": null,
    "paid_date": null,
    "is_first": "0",
    "unsettled": "0",
    "comment": "",
    "params": {
        "ip": "194.186.172.92",
        "landing": "phimp.gif",
        "sales_channel": "",
        "shipping_address.country": "rus",
        "shipping_address.region": "72",
        "signup_url": "",
        "stock_id": "1",
        "storefront": "",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/60.0.3112.113 YaBrowser\/17.9.1.768 Yowser\/2.5 Safari\/537.36"
    },
    "contact": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "admin",
        "email": "1@1.ru",
        "phone": "79773013881",
        "registered": true,
        "photo_50x50": "Fuserpic50.jpg"
    },
    "items": {
        "84": {
            "id": "84",
            "order_id": "62",
            "name": "",
            "product_id": "171115",
            "sku_id": "218488",
            "sku_code": "516781",
            "type": "product",
            "service_id": null,
            "service_variant_id": null,
            "price": "110.7600",
            "quantity": "3",
            "parent_id": null,
            "stock_id": null,
            "virtualstock_id": null,
            "purchase_price": "0.0000",
            "total_discount": "0.0000",
            "image_id": "83660",
            "image_filename": "",
            "sku_image_id": null,
            "ext": "jpg",
            "file_name": "",
            "file_size": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Описал классы:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string contact_id { get; set; }
        public string create_datetime { get; set; }
        public object update_datetime { get; set; }
        public string state_id { get; set; }
        public string total { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string rate { get; set; }
        public string tax { get; set; }
        public string shipping { get; set; }
        public string discount { get; set; }
        public object assigned_contact_id { get; set; }
        public object paid_year { get; set; }
        public object paid_quarter { get; set; }
        public object paid_month { get; set; }
        public object paid_date { get; set; }
        public string is_first { get; set; }
        public string unsettled { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public Params _params { get; set; }
        public Contact contact { get; set; }
        public Items items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Params
    {
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string landing { get; set; }
        public string sales_channel { get; set; }
        public string shipping_addresscountry { get; set; }
        public string shipping_addressregion { get; set; }
        public string signup_url { get; set; }
        public string stock_id { get; set; }
        public string storefront { get; set; }
        public string user_agent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public bool registered { get; set; }
        public string photo_50x50 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public Item[] item { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string order_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string product_id { get; set; }
        public string sku_id { get; set; }
        public string sku_code { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public object service_id { get; set; }
        public object service_variant_id { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }
        public object parent_id { get; set; }
        public object stock_id { get; set; }
        public object virtualstock_id { get; set; }
        public string purchase_price { get; set; }
        public string total_discount { get; set; }
        public string image_id { get; set; }
        public string image_filename { get; set; }
        public object sku_image_id { get; set; }
        public string ext { get; set; }
        public string file_name { get; set; }
        public string file_size { get; set; }
    }
```

Провожу десериализацию

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(str);
```

Ошибок не возникает, но возвращается null, т.е. `Items = Null`.

Грешу на то, что:

```
"items": {
    "84": {
        "id": "84",
        "order_id": "62",
```

Здесь что-то не так.

Как победить?

Comment: "Но проходит без ошибок, об Items = Null" - не совсем понял, как это перевести на русский?

Comment: @0xdb при десериализации ошибок (видимо, исключений) не возникает, но возвращается `null`?

Comment: так точно. 
поспешишь, людей насмешишь !

Comment: вам бы `Item[]` на какой нить `Dictionary<int, Item>` заменить

Comment: @teran спасибо, вроде так понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Все получилось. так работает:

```
public Dictionary<int, Item> items { get; set; }
```

Comment: Вместо  спасибо, не забудьте отметить ответ, который наиболее помог в решении, как принятый.

Answer (score 2):

Классы, кстати, можно генерировать на вот [этом](http://json2csharp.com) сайте.

Конкретно здесь ошибка с названием объекта "84". Такого имени класса существовать не может. Возможно, нужно попробовать изменить невалидные имена и попробовать распарсить еще раз. Классы все же рекомендую взять сгенерированные.

Здесь, кстати, тоже имена невалидные

```
"shipping_address.country": "rus",
"shipping_address.region": "72",
```

Кстати, вот здесь же не массив:

```
"items": {
"84": {
    "id": "84",
    "order_id": "62",
```

[Массив](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) выглядит вот так (в квадратных скобочках):

```
[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

Comment: в том то и дело что входящий json исправить невозможно

Comment: классы генерил с помощью Студии, она это умеет

Comment: Попробуйте изменить свойство public Item[] item { get; set; } на public Item item { get; set; }

Comment: имена вполне валидные с точки зрения `json`. С точки зрения c# в динамическом объекте можно использовать `obj["name.with.dots"]`. Массив выглядит все знают как, а так выглядит словарь `<int, object>`

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно пытаетесь десериализовать словарь

```
public class Order
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string contact_id { get; set; }
    public string create_datetime { get; set; }
    public object update_datetime { get; set; }
    public string state_id { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string rate { get; set; }
    public string tax { get; set; }
    public string shipping { get; set; }
    public string discount { get; set; }
    public object assigned_contact_id { get; set; }
    public object paid_year { get; set; }
    public object paid_quarter { get; set; }
    public object paid_month { get; set; }
    public object paid_date { get; set; }
    public string is_first { get; set; }
    public string unsettled { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public Params _params { get; set; }
    public Contact contact { get; set; }

    // Словарь
    public Dictionary<int, Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно добавить атрибут к некоторым свойствам сгенерированных Студией классов:

```
[JsonProperty("84")]
public _84 _84 { get; set; }
```

А также:

```
[JsonProperty("params")]
public Params _params { get; set; }
```

PS: конечно, желательно переименовать все свойства в соответствии с PascalCase, снабдив их атрибутом `JsonProperty` для маппинга:

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("contact_id")]
public string ContactId { get; set; }
```

И т. д.